# Python refactoring: cleaning up imports

Tags: python, import, refactoring

This might be a newbie-type question (I came to python from PHP5 OO), but I have a few things I am uncertain about the `import` statement in trying to clean up and refactor some of our Python modules.

Let's say, for example, I have a db connection factory module that imports mysqldb and looks something like this:

```
import MySQLdb as mysql
from MySQLdb import cursors
class ConnectionFactory():
  @staticmethod
  def connect(db_host,db_user,db_pass,db,cursor='DictCursor'):
    connection = mysql.connect(host = db_host,
                   user = db_user,
                   passwd = db_pass,
                   db = db,
                   cursorclass=getattr(mysql.cursors, cursor))
    cur = connection.cursor();
    connection.ping(True)
    return (cur,connection)
```

First, **why is that second import, that explicitly grabs `cursors` necessary?**  I can't seem to just access mysql.cursors without it.

Also, let's say another module imports this one to get the db connection and then executes queries using it.

```
import ConnectionFactory
def runquery(q):
  try:
    cur,connection = ConnectionFactory.connect(db_host,db_user,db_pass,db)
    cur.execute(q)
    res = cur.fetchall()
    return res
  except Exception as e:
    log(str(e))
```

Ideally, that Exception that is being caught should be the MySQLdb.Error exception.  **Does this mean that I need to import MySQLdb here too?**  I assume there's a more elegant way of doing this.  I'm not thinking like a Pythonista, I'm sure.

Lastly, let's say both these modules were imported in another parent for use in a WSGI (I have everything coming in through Werkzeug, which then runs a ton of other methods in other modules)

If the WSGI imports both these modules, I assume the things they import individually aren't in its namespace.  **Is it then bad practice to have the same imports across several modules, if ultimately they are going to be used together in one larger one?**

**EDIT**: To clarify that third question,
I've got a special json encoder that's used literally all over the place as the `cls` arg for `json.dumps()`

```
from datetime import datetime
import gnengine
import json

class SpecialEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self,obj):
    if isinstance(obj,set):
        return list(obj)
    elif isinstance(obj,datetime):
        return obj.isoformat()
    elif isinstance(obj,gnengine.searchresult):
        return obj.jsonify()

    return json.JSONEncoder.default(self,obj)
```

`gnengine` is my WSGI, and `searchresult` is a type found within that module.  I'm importing it here because it has its own json method that my encoder needs to expect.  But this encoder obviously is imported for use in `gnengine` as well.  They are essentially importing each other.

My PHP background tells me that this is all solved if the `searchresult` type becomes its own module that represents an object model and then both import that separately.  I'm not sure if this is a big misconception I have though.

Sorry for packaging three questions in one, essentially what I guess is being asked is a clarification about importing in general.  I get the namespacing and why `from name import *` is a bad idea, I just don't understand the best approach when several packages being used together all have similar dependencies.  Is it expected in python to have identical `import`s peppered throughout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I believe that `MySQLdb.cursors` is another module, and that nested modules must be imported separately
2. If you want to specifically catch an exception declared in `MySQLdb`, then yes, you will have to import something.  If you want to catch *any* exception, then you won't have to import.  **But this may not be advisable,** as @tkone explains in a comment below.  Anyway, I don't see the problem with importing something from `MySQLdb` here -- if your database access code is not spread over multiple modules, but rather concentrated in, say, a database access layer, then you won't have too many modules importing from `MySQLdb`.
3. I'm not sure I understand the question.  Could you clarify it?

Comment: Thanks for your help!  Edited to clarify #3.  Seemed vague after I reread it myself.

Comment: On point 2: you should never use `except:` since you'll get unintended side-effects.  For example, lets pretend you were using a list in your try block and if you tried to access a non-existant index on that list, you'd get an `IndexError` which you should handle differently than your MySQLdb exception.

Comment: @tkone That's what I'm trying to avoid and change that catch to a real mysql exception so I can add a general one to the tail, just wasn't clear on the right way to go about getting the mysql specific exceptions in the namespace.

Comment: Excellent.  Yeah, you'll need to explicitly import your exceptions as well.

Answer (score 1):

1. MySQLdb's `__init__.py` (or other instantiation mechanism) does not import cursors, therefore MySQLdb does not know about the cursors' module since it's "just" a subdirectory under it's own directly.  This means you'd need to import it explicitly.
2. You'll need to import the exception directly from MySQLdb.  Like `from MySQLdb import Exception`.  Exceptions are just classes which subclass the Extension class.  Python can't do anything with a class it doesn't know about.  You use the "from" terminology here to only import the parts you need.
3. Nope.  Importing the same objects into a bunch of different files that eventually all work in concert is how Python does it.  The interpreter ensures nothing will foul up runtime or over write anything, etc.  (Try importing the same thing twice in a row -- no errors and you only get one instance of it).

Comment: Thanks!  These are all great to know, especially #3 which I haven't actually tried.

Comment: To clarify on point 3, now that you've updated.  That seems to be a circular import, which Python can handle provided you're "doing it right"  See: http://docs.python.org/faq/programming.html#what-are-the-best-practices-for-using-import-in-a-module

Comment: Ah, perfect!  I missed that bit about circular that when I first went to the faqs.  I actually ended up asking this because the from named import statement was failing in this circular way, which was what first made me think I was doing something against practice.